# I forgot renew my domain and it went to pending delete status. How can I recover the domain now?

Tags: dns

Domain is with Godaddy, status changed to pending delete yesterday. I talked with Godaddy support and they said they can't do anything now, it is too late to redeem the domain. They said I can manually register the domain when it is available again, or backorder it. Should I spend money on backordering or manual registration is enough?

Comment: Please post the whois output. You can omit the actual domain name for privacy but you should mention the extension ie .com. Also, pending delete could be restorable or scheduled for release. It's two different stages of the drop process.

Answer (score 0):

PendingDelete is the last phase of the life-cycle of a GTLD.

Backorder (or drop catching) means to have a software deployed to ‘try to register’ a domain as soon as it becomes available at the registry (the end of the life-cycle is reached). What a back-ordering service does is check at the registry for domain name availability at regular intervals and try to register it as soon as it is available.
There are various providers you can google. Some are CatchTiger, NameJet, SnapNames, DropCatch and even GoDaddy itself.

Backordering always stands a better chance than manually re-registering, as the registrars would know first (via automated software) of domain availability before you will.

Note: A serious domainer will back-order at several services — only one should win and the others should refund you (still, please check individual cases).
Catch.Club says it can kind of aggregate services so that we do not need to back-order at different service providers — but the site is yet to launch. There should be more like this.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is nothing you can do. My advice, just wait until the domain is available again and then you can register again. If you pay in redemption period, it will be very expensive.

Comment: This is not good advice, for several reasons. First, the extension is not stated and the exact status is yet to be clarified. Second, any domain that is remotely valuable is going to be caught by some backorder service or a private dropcatcher. There is no guarantee whatsoever the OP will be able to manually register the domain again when it drops. If the domains ends up with some backorder service, there could be an auction involving multiple participants, and the final price could be much higher than the redemption fee, depending on the perceived or actual value of the domain name.